# logic error in string reversal C

Tags: c, string, loops

`Input: Hello there boy(any 80 character string)`

`Expected output: boy there Hello`

`Current output: (nothing - does compile though) \`

My HW prompt:

Write a program that prompts the user for a sequence of words separated by one or more spaces, where each word is a sequence of alpha-numeric characters. You can assume that the text string entered is no more than 80 characters long, and each word is no more than 20 characters long. Use the fgets() command in  to read the input text string. For example, we can declare a char array char sentence[81]; then use fgets(sentence,81,stdin); to read in up to 80 characters from the standard input stdin (i.e. keyboard input) into the character array sentence[], which will also insert a null character (string termination character) at the end of the array; this is why the array needs to be one byte longer than the entered text. Your program should print the words out in reverse order, exactly as entered with exactly one space between each word. You can assume there are no punctuation marks or control characters entered. Your program should be named reverse_words.c, and your output should match exactly the output shown for the example below.

I have looked at other examples and just trying to use what I know to make this program. To me it seems to work, yet it doesn't. Can someone please help me find my where my logic is off?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
   char sentence[81];
   char space[81];
   int i , h = 0, j, start;

   printf("Enter a sentance (up to 80 characters): ");
   fgets(sentence,81,stdin);

   //starting backwards go from element 80 to find first non space
   //make array to store element numbers of sentence in new array
   for(i = 80; i >= 0; i--)
   {
     if(sentence[i] != ' ' || sentence[i] != '\0')
     { start = i;
       //printf("%i", start);
     }
    if(i < start && i == ' ')
   {
     space[h] = i;
     h++;
  }
}

h = 0;

  //start at first space and print characters till next space, repeat till all words printed
  for( j = space[h]; j < space[h + 1]; h++)
  {
     printf("%c", sentence[j]);
     if (j == space[h + 1])
        printf(" ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does this mean `i==' '` you are doing in` if` condition

Comment: Looking again i think it should be sentence[i] == ' '. I am trying to find all the spaces between words. Ex. hi'_'there'_'boy

Comment: You can always edit your post and fix a mistakes if it doesn't change the purpose of the question or if the problem is still there.

Comment: Seems like a perfect question for a recursive solution. At least I would solve this with recursion.

Comment: When a sting is input and there are 81 elements stored in memory for is this how it stores Hello world? What comes after the d? should the line space != 'space' really be sentence[i] != NULL && sentence[i] != '\0'?

Comment: Better replace this "I have looked at other examples and just trying to use what I know to make this program" with explaination the logics in English.

Answer (score 2):

From a cursory glance

```
if(i < start && i == ' ')
```

Change to

```
 if(i < start && sentence[i] == ' ')
```

Other things you can improve:

Do not loop from 80, instead find the length of string entered and then go backwards. Use `strlen`

Answer (score 0):

This portion of code can be cleaned up a bit:

```
//starting backwards go from element 80 to find first non space
//make array to store element numbers of sentence in new array
```

Instead of marching back from 80 characters, just take the `strlen()` of `sentence`:

```
printf("Enter a sentence (up to 80 characters): ");
fgets(sentence, 81, stdin);
start = (int) strlen(sentence) - 1; /* subtract one to account for null character */
```

Then work your way back from that value:

```
for (i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
    /* ... */
}
```

You can also improve the general quality of your code by defining and using a constant to represent the maximum length of a sentence:

```
#define MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH 80
...
char sentence[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH + 1];
char space[MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH + 1];
...
printf("Enter a sentence (up to %d characters): ", MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH);
fgets(sentence, MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH + 1, stdin);
```

Then, if you want to use a different limit, you only have to change code in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code try to run this :

```
int len=strlen(sentence);
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   space[i]=sentence[len-1-i];
space[i]='\0'
int start=0,end;
for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
{     
   if(space[i]!=' ' || space[i]!='\0')  //edited in place of && it should be ||
   {}
   else 
   {
      end=i-1;
      str_rev(&space[start],&space[end]);
      start=i+1;
   }
}


void str_rev(char *s,char*e)
{
   while(s>e)
   {
      char tmp=*s;
      *s=*e;
      *e=tmp;
      s++;
      e--;
   }
}
```

Comment: has some warnings... 
reverse_words.c:67:39: warning: multi-character character constant
reverse_words.c: In function 'main':
reverse_words.c:71: warning: implicit declaration of function 'str_rev'
/tmp/ccdZzmLZ.o: In function `main':
reverse_words.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `str_rev'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: try to give declaration of `str-rev()` at the top before calling of `str_rev()` and also edited in place of `&&` it should be `||`

Comment: Always give forward declaration of function if the actual definition is below the calling enviroment

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment, this is a perfect question for recursion. That's why I wanted to share this solution. Of course, don't use it unless you fully understand what is happening :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void PrintWordsInReverseOrder(char* sentence)
{
    // Search beginning of word (skipping non-readable characters <= ' ')
    char* start = sentence;
    while ((*start != '\0') && (*start <= ' ')) start++;
    if (*start == '\0') return; // this is the end my friend
    // Search end of word (skipping readable characters > ' ')
    char* end = start;
    while (*end > ' ') end++; // will also stop at '\0'
    if (*end != '\0')
    {   // We are not at the end of the string, so there might be a next word available.
        // Print the next word using recursion (this causes to print out the last word first)
        PrintWordsInReverseOrder(end + 1);
    }
    char endBackup = *end;
    *end = '\0'; // temporary terminate the word so we can print it out (don't be affraid, we have a backup in endBackup)
    printf(start);
    printf(" ");
    *end = endBackup; // restore word termination char
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[81];
    printf("Enter a sentance (up to 80 characters): ");
    fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin);
    PrintWordsInReverseOrder(sentence);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yup it works beautifully! Thanks but I am kinda lost with pointers. My HW is due Tuesday so I still have time to look over this but for now I have to go. I'll post questions tomorrow after I go pointers some more if you are free to help...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <conio.h>

void main()
{
   int x=0,y=0,t,i=0,j=1,k=0,p[10];
   char a[80],b[80];
   clrscr();
   printf(" enter a string ");
   gets(a);
   p[0]=0;
   //count char in string
   while(a[i]!= '\0')
   {
      i++;
      //array p[] note the space position in string
      if(a[i]==' ')
      {
         p[j]=i;
         j++;
      }
   }
   k=i;
   t=0;
   //loop till space to next space
   for(j=j-1;j>=0;j--)
   {    
      x=p[j];
      y=x;
      //reposition the words
      while(x<k)
      {
         // put space when it come to first position
         // because at the beginning there is no space
         if (x==0)
         {
            b[t]= ' ';
            t++;
         }
         b[t]=a[x];
         t++;
         x++;
      }
      k=y;
   }
   puts(b);
   getch();
}
```